# ListView lags when loading from application cache

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, drawable

I wrote a little piece of code that download image from internet and cache them into cache dir.
**It runs in a secondary thread.**

```
{

    String hash = md5(urlString);
    File f = new File(m_cacheDir, hash);

    if (f.exists())
    {
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
        return d;
    }

    try {
        InputStream is = download(urlString);
        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");

        if (drawable != null)
        {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        }

        return drawable;
    } catch (Throwable e) { }

    return null;
}
```

I use this code to load picture inside a ListView item, and it works fine. If I remove the first if (where i load image from disk) it runs smoothly (and download picture every time!). If I keep it, when you scroll listview you feel some lags during picture's loading from disk, why?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "why", I experienced this with lots of gc() messages in my logcat. Android allocates the memory before decoding the file from disk which could cause garbage collection, which is painful for the performance in all threads. Probably the same happens when you encode your jpeg as well.

For decoding part you can try reuse existing bitmap if you have one to let Android decode image in-place. Please have a look at the following snippet:

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inMutable = true;
if (oldBitmap != null) {
    options.inBitmap = oldBitmap;
}
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

Do in background.( use AsyncTask to load images.)

Comment: But u don't need to download all the images when u creat ur adapter object, 1st download the visible views images after the scraps.